# If var is under a certain number descending do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, integer

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw4j2/6/

Trying to change attributes to a selector if the seconds count is 10 or under.

I'm using

```
var returnSecondsNumber = $('.countdownSecond > .countSeconds > .position:first-child > .digit').text() + $('.countdownSecond > .countSeconds > .position:nth-child(2) > .digit').text();
```

To grab the numbers from both spans and returns it as 16/15/14/etc.

Now I need do something if this numeric is under 10.

e.g.

```
    if (returnsSecondsNumber <= 10) 
       { $(this).addClass('urgent'); 
       }, else { //do something 
       }
```

I've tried taking a look at parseInt with no success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd annotate the jsfiddle to show where it is that you want to do that; it's not at all clear.  Also, what is it that doesn't work with what you've tried?

Comment: Updated jsFiddle with some comments on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well the thing is that comment you added would be an odd place to put the code you're describing; that's the start of the "ready" handler and it only runs once. Do you just want to check the value once, or do you want to check on every "tick"?

Comment: Technically every tick it would need to check since they are being reiterated every change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. First, you need to move the code that constructs "returnSecondsNumber" into the callback function(s) of whichever timers you want to monitor.
2. Second, just use `parseInt()`:

   ```
   var numericVal = parseInt(returnsSecondsNumber, 10);
   if (!isNaN(numericVal) && numericVal < 10) {
     // do whatever
   }
   ```

Comment: I have this working to an extent, was never able to set those variables so my selectors are huge. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(!isNaN(parseInt(returnsSecondsNumber )) && returnsSecondsNumber < 11)
    //Do stuff...
```

One thing to keep in mind is that if the value of returnsSecondNumber is a starts with a number that  will be returned instead of NaN

Comment: returnsSecondsNumber is showing up as undefined in the console.

Comment: But if I don't set it as a variable and just use $('.countdownSecond > .countSeconds > .position:first-child > .digit').text() + $('.countdownSecond > .countSeconds > .position:nth-child(2) > .digit').text(); it returns my value.

Comment: parseInt(x, 10) - it's usually better to include that radix parameter than deal with the consequences of weird things happening because it's ommited

Comment: Still having problems with my variable being undefined. =\

Comment: If you've defined a variable (your returnsSecondsNumber = ) then it shouldn't be evaluated as undefined.